# Display Custom Number Instead Of Original Number In Send Message.Is It Possible In Twilio?

Tags: php, laravel-5, twilio

I have US twilio Number,I sent Message From US Number But Receiver Display My Own Indian Number.Instead Of Twilio Number.
I was enable Alphanumeric Sender ID In My Twilio Account(Trial Account),If I set From Parameter with my Indian Number I getting Error. 
Is It Possible?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Sending international SMS messages can have various results. We recently launched guidelines for every country we deliver to. You might be interested in the [SMS guidelines for India](https://www.twilio.com/sms/guidelines/in).

Crucially, messages sent from long codes (normal phone numbers) aren't guaranteed to have their sender ID preserved. You can pre-register an alphanumeric ID that will be preserved though. Perhaps that is something you can look into?

Comment: My error is Solved...
Now My Question Is That,I Was Enable Alphanumeric Sender Id In my Twilio Account For US Number.I Sent Message From Us To Indian Number but Receiver Display My US Number Instead Of My Alphanumeric Name(Which is set in my twilio account).

Comment: How are you setting the alphanumeric ID?

Comment: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133867-Using-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID-with-Messaging-Services

Comment: Using a messaging service? OK, cool, and can you share the code you're using to send the message now? Thanks!

Comment: Ok, all that looks correct. I think you need to pre-register your alphanumeric sender. To do so, just contact [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and they can get you started on pre-registration.

Comment: try {
        $sid = "AC015f0202b71c90483003dd57f787c6af";
        $token = "e74449f9c779635eac324b6827cXXXXX";
        $client = new Client($sid, $token);

        $client->messages->create(
                "+919048451555", array(
            'messagingServiceSid' => "MG01d4a3519474d8a7606644f772a331eb",
            'body' => "copilot example with alphanum"
                )
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

Comment: Okay..Thank You !!